# Access list elements on jsp using attributes

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I wanna to access the list elements inside my JSP page using the attributes not the (Index) number.

**First :** I get a list of items in my controller as :

```
List<Item> items;
```

**Second :** I send it as Model Attribute to my JSP page

**Third :** I access the list through forEach tag :

```
<c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">

       ${role[1]}

</c:forEach>
```

As you see , I used the index number for the column , but actually I wanna to use the attribute name instead :

```
${role.code}
```

But when I do that I got an Exception :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "code"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.roles.roles_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(roles_jsp.java:559)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.roles.roles_jsp._jspService(roles_jsp.java:352)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**What is the cause of this problem ? How I can prepare for using the attributes ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case I have to use HQL instead of Typical SQL in order to cast the result into real Java Object.

I test that approach , and it is working !